# How do I purchase a game on Origin?

Tags: origin

I would like to know how to purchase a game from origin, once i add it to the cart, i get lost from there, I don't know the procedure after that. I saved my credit card and my Paypal account both on the origin account.

Answer (score 2):

Add it to the cart, then press Checkout followed by Proceed to Checkout.  Then enter your payment details and continue through that process until it's done.